# How connect Firebase Crashlytics to Cordova Version (10.0.0) project?

Tags: android, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, crashlytics

Android and iOs app is written on ionic 1 how connect Firebase Crashlytics to an app?
I’ve tried to connect via Firebase Documentation, but it failed, the reason may be the old version of Cordova.

**class org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$DefaultDirectoryVar$2 cannot be cast to class org.gradle.api.file.Directory (org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$DefaultDirectoryVar$2 and org.gradle.api.file.Directory are in unnamed module of loader org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader @4678c730)
class org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$DefaultDirectoryVar$2 cannot be cast to class org.gradle.api.file.Directory (org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$DefaultDirectoryVar$2 and org.gradle.api.file.Directory are in unnamed module of loader org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader @4678c730)**

**Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)**

**Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.**

**Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.**

**In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.**

Answer (score 0):

we're using these plugins

```
"cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics": "^6.1.0",
"cordova-plugin-firebase-crash": "^4.1.2",
```

but to handle that we had to upgrade cordova platforms to

```
"cordova-android": "^9.1.0",
"cordova-ios": "^6.2.0",
```

for Android it works well, but right now I'm trying to figure out iOS platform, because after upgrade and apply breaking changes splashscreen is displayed all the time :(